# Word Cloud python library displays an apostrophe at the end of every word

Tags: python, nltk, word-cloud

I used `nltk.tokenize` to tokenize a txt file and it generated a new file, let's call it "File_B".

Then I run:

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

text = open('File_B').read()

wordcloud = WordCloud(width=1600, height=800).generate(text)

wordcloud = WordCloud(font_path=font_path, width=1600, height=800).generate(text)
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation="bilinear")
plt.axis("off")
plt.tight_layout(pad=0)
plt.savefig("wordcloud.png", bbox_inches='tight')
```

This is the result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnoJ7.png

There's an apostrophe at the end of every word, even if they're not there in File_B. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The apostrophe doesn't appear when I transform the tokenized text into a string:

```
string_text = ' '.join(tokenized_text)    
wordcloud = WordCloud(width=1600, height=800).generate(string_text)
```